# Pull audio data from graph kAudioUnitSubType_GenericOutput

Tags: macos, core-audio

I am constructing audio graph, which has:
AudioFilePlayer (Generator unit) -> GenericOutput (Output unit)

The basic idea:

AudioFilePlayer is producing audio frames to it's output. Generic output takes data from AudioFilePlayer's output as input. Than I can take that data and save it to other buffer.

My question is how to pull data from generic output to get data for offline rendering.

I did some research on it, and find out that I have to use AudioUnitRender on GenericOutput unit to pull audio data from it.

```
Uint32 frames = 512;
timestamp.mSampleTime = 0;

... While Loop ...

timestamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;

bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = param->inputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = frames * param->inputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(float);
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = NULL;

AudioUnitRenderActionFlags flags = 0;

OSStatus error = noErr;
if ((error = AudioUnitRender(param->genericOutput, &flags, &timestamp, 0, frames, &bufferList)) != noErr)
{
    printf("Cannot AudioUnitRender: %d\n", error);
}

timestamp.mSampleTime += frames;
```

**But i get error with number -50.**

Am I setting input parameters wrong? Do I need to register any render callback functions to GenericOutput unit?

Comment: -50 is the parameter list error, debug `param->genericOutput` once and make sure that this isn't NULL.

Comment: I got it working. Here you can find my working code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297990/core-audio-offline-rendering-genericoutput/15361251#15361251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I set GenericOutput StreamFormat after calling AUGraphInitialize().
It must be done before that.

I used CAShow(reader.graph) to get log of audio graph, which helped me to notice that format is't changed after trying to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you successfully done the offline rendering using `GenericOutput` node.
Could you please give some details how you did this.

- You are trying to pass a buffer list with no data in it, in loop.
- If we need to save the output to a file what i have to do (or where I put `ExtAudioFileWriteAsync`).
- What is the exit condition for your while loop.
- is `timestamp` is a local declared variable.

Comment: Yes, timeStamp is local variable.

Comment: I allocate memory for number of frames I want to read.

  bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
  bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = pFormat->mChannelsPerFrame;
  bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = pFormat->mBytesPerFrame * framesToRead;
  bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = (UInt8 *) malloc(bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);

You should put ExtAudioFileWriteAsync right after AudioUnitRender call. I get total length of file in frames, when i reach that number i terminate loop.