# core audio offline rendering GenericOutput

Tags: ios, core-audio

Anybody successfully done offline rendering using core-Audio.?

I had to mix two audio files and apply reverb(used 2 AudioFilePlayer,MultiChannelMixer,Reverb2 and RemoteIO).
Got it working. and i could save it while its previewing(on renderCallBack of RemoteIO).

I need to save it without playing it (offline).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Offline rendering Worked for me using GenericOutput AudioUnit.
I am sharing the working code here.
core-audio framework seems a little though. But small-small things in it like ASBD, parameters  ...etc are making these issues. try hard it will work. Don't give-up :-). core-audio is very powerful and useful while dealing with low-level audio. Thats what I learned from these last weeks. Enjoy :-D ....

Declare these in .h

```
//AUGraph
AUGraph mGraph;
//Audio Unit References
AudioUnit mFilePlayer;
AudioUnit mFilePlayer2;
AudioUnit mReverb;
AudioUnit mTone;
AudioUnit mMixer;
AudioUnit mGIO;
//Audio File Location
AudioFileID inputFile;
AudioFileID inputFile2;
//Audio file refereces for saving
ExtAudioFileRef extAudioFile;
//Standard sample rate
Float64 graphSampleRate;
AudioStreamBasicDescription stereoStreamFormat864;

Float64 MaxSampleTime;
```

//in .m class

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    graphSampleRate = 44100.0;
    MaxSampleTime   = 0.0;
    UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    CheckError(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                                   sizeof(category),
                                   &category),
           "Couldn't set category on audio session");
    [self initializeAUGraph];
    return self;
}
```

//ASBD setup

```
- (void) setupStereoStream864 {    
    // The AudioUnitSampleType data type is the recommended type for sample data in audio
    // units. This obtains the byte size of the type for use in filling in the ASBD.
    size_t bytesPerSample = sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType);
    // Fill the application audio format struct's fields to define a linear PCM,
    // stereo, noninterleaved stream at the hardware sample rate.
    stereoStreamFormat864.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    stereoStreamFormat864.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical;
    stereoStreamFormat864.mBytesPerPacket    = bytesPerSample;
    stereoStreamFormat864.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
    stereoStreamFormat864.mBytesPerFrame     = bytesPerSample;
    stereoStreamFormat864.mChannelsPerFrame  = 2; // 2 indicates stereo
    stereoStreamFormat864.mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * bytesPerSample;
    stereoStreamFormat864.mSampleRate        = graphSampleRate;
}
```

//AUGraph setup

```
- (void)initializeAUGraph
{
    [self setupStereoStream864];

    // Setup the AUGraph, add AUNodes, and make connections
// create a new AUGraph
CheckError(NewAUGraph(&mGraph),"Couldn't create new graph");

// AUNodes represent AudioUnits on the AUGraph and provide an
// easy means for connecting audioUnits together.
    AUNode filePlayerNode;
    AUNode filePlayerNode2;
AUNode mixerNode;
AUNode reverbNode;
AUNode toneNode;
AUNode gOutputNode;

// file player component
    AudioComponentDescription filePlayer_desc;
filePlayer_desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Generator;
filePlayer_desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer;
filePlayer_desc.componentFlags = 0;
filePlayer_desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
filePlayer_desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

// file player component2
    AudioComponentDescription filePlayer2_desc;
filePlayer2_desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Generator;
filePlayer2_desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer;
filePlayer2_desc.componentFlags = 0;
filePlayer2_desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
filePlayer2_desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

// Create AudioComponentDescriptions for the AUs we want in the graph
// mixer component
AudioComponentDescription mixer_desc;
mixer_desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Mixer;
mixer_desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer;
mixer_desc.componentFlags = 0;
mixer_desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
mixer_desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

// Create AudioComponentDescriptions for the AUs we want in the graph
// Reverb component
AudioComponentDescription reverb_desc;
reverb_desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
reverb_desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2;
reverb_desc.componentFlags = 0;
reverb_desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
reverb_desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;


//tone component
    AudioComponentDescription tone_desc;
tone_desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_FormatConverter;
//tone_desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch;
    tone_desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_Varispeed;
tone_desc.componentFlags = 0;
tone_desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
tone_desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;


    AudioComponentDescription gOutput_desc;
gOutput_desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
gOutput_desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_GenericOutput;
gOutput_desc.componentFlags = 0;
gOutput_desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
gOutput_desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

//Add nodes to graph

// Add nodes to the graph to hold our AudioUnits,
// You pass in a reference to the  AudioComponentDescription
// and get back an  AudioUnit
    AUGraphAddNode(mGraph, &filePlayer_desc, &filePlayerNode );
    AUGraphAddNode(mGraph, &filePlayer2_desc, &filePlayerNode2 );
    AUGraphAddNode(mGraph, &mixer_desc, &mixerNode );
    AUGraphAddNode(mGraph, &reverb_desc, &reverbNode );
    AUGraphAddNode(mGraph, &tone_desc, &toneNode );
AUGraphAddNode(mGraph, &gOutput_desc, &gOutputNode);


//Open the graph early, initialize late
// open the graph AudioUnits are open but not initialized (no resource allocation occurs here)

CheckError(AUGraphOpen(mGraph),"Couldn't Open the graph");

//Reference to Nodes
// get the reference to the AudioUnit object for the file player graph node
AUGraphNodeInfo(mGraph, filePlayerNode, NULL, &mFilePlayer);
AUGraphNodeInfo(mGraph, filePlayerNode2, NULL, &mFilePlayer2);
    AUGraphNodeInfo(mGraph, reverbNode, NULL, &mReverb);
    AUGraphNodeInfo(mGraph, toneNode, NULL, &mTone);
    AUGraphNodeInfo(mGraph, mixerNode, NULL, &mMixer);
AUGraphNodeInfo(mGraph, gOutputNode, NULL, &mGIO);

    AUGraphConnectNodeInput(mGraph, filePlayerNode, 0, reverbNode, 0);
    AUGraphConnectNodeInput(mGraph, reverbNode, 0, toneNode, 0);
    AUGraphConnectNodeInput(mGraph, toneNode, 0, mixerNode,0);
    AUGraphConnectNodeInput(mGraph, filePlayerNode2, 0, mixerNode, 1);
AUGraphConnectNodeInput(mGraph, mixerNode, 0, gOutputNode, 0);


    UInt32 busCount   = 2;    // bus count for mixer unit input

//Setup mixer unit bus count
    CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty (
                                 mMixer,
                                 kAudioUnitProperty_ElementCount,
                                 kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                 0,
                                 &busCount,
                                 sizeof (busCount)
                                 ),
           "Couldn't set mixer unit's bus count");

//Enable metering mode to view levels input and output levels of mixer
    UInt32 onValue = 1;
    CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(mMixer,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_MeteringMode,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                0,
                                &onValue,
                                sizeof(onValue)),
           "error");

// Increase the maximum frames per slice allows the mixer unit to accommodate the
//    larger slice size used when the screen is locked.
    UInt32 maximumFramesPerSlice = 4096;

    CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty (
                                 mMixer,
                                 kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice,
                                 kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                 0,
                                 &maximumFramesPerSlice,
                                 sizeof (maximumFramesPerSlice)
                                 ),
           "Couldn't set mixer units maximum framers per slice");

// set the audio data format of tone Unit
    AudioUnitSetProperty(mTone,
                     kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                     0,
                     &stereoStreamFormat864,
                     sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));
// set the audio data format of reverb Unit
    AudioUnitSetProperty(mReverb,
                     kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                     0,
                     &stereoStreamFormat864,
                     sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));

// set initial reverb
    AudioUnitParameterValue reverbTime = 2.5;
    AudioUnitSetParameter(mReverb, 4, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, reverbTime, 0);
    AudioUnitSetParameter(mReverb, 5, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, reverbTime, 0);
    AudioUnitSetParameter(mReverb, 0, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, 0, 0);

    AudioStreamBasicDescription     auEffectStreamFormat;
    UInt32 asbdSize = sizeof (auEffectStreamFormat);
memset (&auEffectStreamFormat, 0, sizeof (auEffectStreamFormat ));

// get the audio data format from reverb
CheckError(AudioUnitGetProperty(mReverb,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                0,
                                &auEffectStreamFormat,
                                &asbdSize),
           "Couldn't get aueffectunit ASBD");


    auEffectStreamFormat.mSampleRate = graphSampleRate;

// set the audio data format of mixer Unit
    CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(mMixer,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                0,
                                &auEffectStreamFormat, sizeof(auEffectStreamFormat)),
           "Couldn't set ASBD on mixer output");

CheckError(AUGraphInitialize(mGraph),"Couldn't Initialize the graph");

    [self setUpAUFilePlayer];
    [self setUpAUFilePlayer2];  
}
```

//Audio file playback setup here i am setting the voice file

```
-(OSStatus) setUpAUFilePlayer{
NSString *songPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"testVoice" ofType:@".m4a"];
CFURLRef songURL = ( CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:songPath];

// open the input audio file
CheckError(AudioFileOpenURL(songURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &inputFile),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer AudioFileOpenURL failed");

AudioStreamBasicDescription fileASBD;
// get the audio data format from the file
UInt32 propSize = sizeof(fileASBD);
CheckError(AudioFileGetProperty(inputFile, kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat,
                                &propSize, &fileASBD),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer couldn't get file's data format");

// tell the file player unit to load the file we want to play
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(mFilePlayer, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileIDs,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &inputFile, sizeof(inputFile)),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileIDs] failed");

UInt64 nPackets;
UInt32 propsize = sizeof(nPackets);
CheckError(AudioFileGetProperty(inputFile, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount,
                                &propsize, &nPackets),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer AudioFileGetProperty[kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount] failed");

// tell the file player AU to play the entire file
ScheduledAudioFileRegion rgn;
memset (&rgn.mTimeStamp, 0, sizeof(rgn.mTimeStamp));
rgn.mTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
rgn.mTimeStamp.mSampleTime = 0;
rgn.mCompletionProc = NULL;
rgn.mCompletionProcUserData = NULL;
rgn.mAudioFile = inputFile;
rgn.mLoopCount = -1;
rgn.mStartFrame = 0;
rgn.mFramesToPlay = nPackets * fileASBD.mFramesPerPacket;

if (MaxSampleTime < rgn.mFramesToPlay)
{
    MaxSampleTime = rgn.mFramesToPlay;
}

CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(mFilePlayer, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0,&rgn, sizeof(rgn)),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer1 AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion] failed");

// prime the file player AU with default values
UInt32 defaultVal = 0;

CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(mFilePlayer, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFilePrime,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &defaultVal, sizeof(defaultVal)),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFilePrime] failed");


// tell the file player AU when to start playing (-1 sample time means next render cycle)
AudioTimeStamp startTime;
memset (&startTime, 0, sizeof(startTime));
startTime.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;

startTime.mSampleTime = -1;
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(mFilePlayer, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleStartTimeStamp,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &startTime, sizeof(startTime)),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleStartTimeStamp]");

return noErr;  
}
```

//Audio file playback setup here i am setting the BGMusic file

```
-(OSStatus) setUpAUFilePlayer2{
NSString *songPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"BGmusic" ofType:@".mp3"];
CFURLRef songURL = ( CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:songPath];

// open the input audio file
CheckError(AudioFileOpenURL(songURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &inputFile2),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer2 AudioFileOpenURL failed");

AudioStreamBasicDescription fileASBD;
// get the audio data format from the file
UInt32 propSize = sizeof(fileASBD);
CheckError(AudioFileGetProperty(inputFile2, kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat,
                                &propSize, &fileASBD),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer2 couldn't get file's data format");

// tell the file player unit to load the file we want to play
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(mFilePlayer2, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileIDs,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &inputFile2, sizeof(inputFile2)),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer2 AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileIDs] failed");

UInt64 nPackets;
UInt32 propsize = sizeof(nPackets);
CheckError(AudioFileGetProperty(inputFile2, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount,
                                &propsize, &nPackets),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer2 AudioFileGetProperty[kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount] failed");

// tell the file player AU to play the entire file
ScheduledAudioFileRegion rgn;
memset (&rgn.mTimeStamp, 0, sizeof(rgn.mTimeStamp));
rgn.mTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
rgn.mTimeStamp.mSampleTime = 0;
rgn.mCompletionProc = NULL;
rgn.mCompletionProcUserData = NULL;
rgn.mAudioFile = inputFile2;
rgn.mLoopCount = -1;
rgn.mStartFrame = 0;
rgn.mFramesToPlay = nPackets * fileASBD.mFramesPerPacket;


if (MaxSampleTime < rgn.mFramesToPlay)
{
    MaxSampleTime = rgn.mFramesToPlay;
}

CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(mFilePlayer2, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0,&rgn, sizeof(rgn)),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer2 AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion] failed");

// prime the file player AU with default values
UInt32 defaultVal = 0;
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(mFilePlayer2, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFilePrime,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &defaultVal, sizeof(defaultVal)),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer2 AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFilePrime] failed");


// tell the file player AU when to start playing (-1 sample time means next render cycle)
AudioTimeStamp startTime;
memset (&startTime, 0, sizeof(startTime));
startTime.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
startTime.mSampleTime = -1;
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(mFilePlayer2, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleStartTimeStamp,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &startTime, sizeof(startTime)),
           "setUpAUFilePlayer2 AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleStartTimeStamp]");

return noErr;  
}
```

//Start Saving File

```
- (void)startRecordingAAC{
AudioStreamBasicDescription destinationFormat;
memset(&destinationFormat, 0, sizeof(destinationFormat));
destinationFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
destinationFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
UInt32 size = sizeof(destinationFormat);
OSStatus result = AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo, 0, NULL, &size, &destinationFormat);
if(result) printf("AudioFormatGetProperty %ld \n", result);
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];



NSString *destinationFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@/output.m4a", documentsDirectory];
CFURLRef destinationURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                        (CFStringRef)destinationFilePath,
                                                        kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle,
                                                        false);
[destinationFilePath release];

// specify codec Saving the output in .m4a format
result = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(destinationURL,
                                   kAudioFileM4AType,
                                   &destinationFormat,
                                   NULL,
                                   kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                                   &extAudioFile);
if(result) printf("ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL %ld \n", result);
CFRelease(destinationURL);

// This is a very important part and easiest way to set the ASBD for the File with correct format.
AudioStreamBasicDescription clientFormat;
UInt32 fSize = sizeof (clientFormat);
memset(&clientFormat, 0, sizeof(clientFormat));
// get the audio data format from the Output Unit
CheckError(AudioUnitGetProperty(mGIO,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                0,
                                &clientFormat,
                                &fSize),"AudioUnitGetProperty on failed");

// set the audio data format of mixer Unit
CheckError(ExtAudioFileSetProperty(extAudioFile,
                                   kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                                   sizeof(clientFormat),
                                   &clientFormat),
           "ExtAudioFileSetProperty kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat failed");
// specify codec
UInt32 codec = kAppleHardwareAudioCodecManufacturer;
CheckError(ExtAudioFileSetProperty(extAudioFile,
                                   kExtAudioFileProperty_CodecManufacturer,
                                   sizeof(codec),
                                   &codec),"ExtAudioFileSetProperty on extAudioFile Faild");

CheckError(ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(extAudioFile, 0, NULL),"ExtAudioFileWriteAsync Failed");

[self pullGenericOutput];
}
```

// Manual Feeding and getting data/Buffer from the GenericOutput Node.

```
-(void)pullGenericOutput{
AudioUnitRenderActionFlags flags = 0;
AudioTimeStamp inTimeStamp;
memset(&inTimeStamp, 0, sizeof(AudioTimeStamp));
inTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
UInt32 busNumber = 0;
UInt32 numberFrames = 512;
inTimeStamp.mSampleTime = 0;
int channelCount = 2;

NSLog(@"Final numberFrames :%li",numberFrames);
int totFrms = MaxSampleTime;
while (totFrms > 0)
{
    if (totFrms < numberFrames)
    {
        numberFrames = totFrms;
        NSLog(@"Final numberFrames :%li",numberFrames);
    }
    else
    {
        totFrms -= numberFrames;
    }
    AudioBufferList *bufferList = (AudioBufferList*)malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList)+sizeof(AudioBuffer)*(channelCount-1));
    bufferList->mNumberBuffers = channelCount;
    for (int j=0; j<channelCount; j++)
    {
        AudioBuffer buffer = {0};
        buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
        buffer.mDataByteSize = numberFrames*sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType);
        buffer.mData = calloc(numberFrames, sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType));

        bufferList->mBuffers[j] = buffer;

    }
    CheckError(AudioUnitRender(mGIO,
                               &flags,
                               &inTimeStamp,
                               busNumber,
                               numberFrames,
                               bufferList),
               "AudioUnitRender mGIO");



    CheckError(ExtAudioFileWrite(extAudioFile, numberFrames, bufferList),("extaudiofilewrite fail"));

}

[self FilesSavingCompleted];
}
```

//FilesSavingCompleted

```
-(void)FilesSavingCompleted{
OSStatus status = ExtAudioFileDispose(extAudioFile);
printf("OSStatus(ExtAudioFileDispose): %ld\n", status);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code is very helpful!! I've spend a couple days trying to make such thing, and than I found it - very nice!

Comment: I see the TimePitch line is commented out and Varispeed has been used in this example. So, we expect this to also work with TimePitch?

Answer (score 5):

One way to do offline rendering is to remove the RemoteIO unit and explicitly call `AudioUnitRender` on the right-most unit in your graph (either the mixer or the reverb unit depending on your topology). By doing this in a loop until you exhaust the samples from both of your source files, and writing the resulting sample buffers with Extended Audio File Services, you can create a compressed audio file of the mixdown. You'll want to do this on a background thread to keep the UI responsive, but I've used this technique before with some success.

Answer (score 3):

Above code is working on iOS7 device but not working on iOS8 device and on all simulators.
I had replaced the following code segment

```
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    CheckError(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                                   sizeof(category),
                                   &category),
           "Couldn't set category on audio session");
```

with the following code. Because AudioSessionSetProperty is deprecated so I had replaced following code.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

        NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
        if (![session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                      withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                            error:&setCategoryError]) {
            // handle error
        }
```

There must be some update for iOS 8. which can be in above code or in some where else.

Answer (score 1):

I followed Abdusha's approach but my output file had no audio plus the size was very small as compared to the input. After looking into it, a fix I made was in "pullGenericOutput" function. After AudioUnitRender call:

```
AudioUnitRender(genericOutputUnit,
                                   &flags,
                                   &inTimeStamp,
                                   busNumber,
                                   numberFrames,
                                       bufferList);

inTimeStamp.mSampleTime++; //Updated
```

increment the timeStamp by 1. After doing this, the output file was perfect with effects working. Thanks. Your answer helped a lot.