# core audio offline rendering issue on iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, core-audio, audiounit

I want to apply reverb effect on a sound file and want to save it on disk using Core Audio. I successfully apply the effect and played it using kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO. Now I want to save it on disk so I use kAudioUnitSubType_GenericOutput and call AudioUnitRender and I used same code listed below.

[core audio offline rendering GenericOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297990/core-audio-offline-rendering-genericoutput/15361251#15361251)

Now Problem is that when I run same code from above link on iOS7 it works fine.
When I run it on iOS 8 device it simply save a file having no sound.
Can any one help me?

Thanks