# SWIFT - Is it possible to save audio from AVAudioEngine, or from AudioPlayerNode? If yes, how?

Tags: swift, avasset, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode, avaudiofile

I've been looking around Swift documentation to **save an audio output from AVAudioEngine** but I couldn't find any useful tip.
Any suggestion?

**Solution**
I found a way around thanks to matt's answer.
Here a sample code of how to save an audio after passing it through an AVAudioEngine *(i think that technically it's before)*

```
newAudio = AVAudioFile(forWriting: newAudio.url, settings: nil, error: NSErrorPointer()) 
//Your new file on which you want to save some changed audio, and prepared to be bufferd in some new data...

var audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode() //or your Time pitch unit if pitch changed   

//Now install a Tap on the output bus to "record" the transformed file on a our newAudio file.
audioPlayerNode.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize: (AVAudioFrameCount(audioPlayer.duration)), format: opffb){
        (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!)  in 

        if (self.newAudio.length) < (self.audioFile.length){//Let us know when to stop saving the file, otherwise saving infinitely

        self.newAudio.writeFromBuffer(buffer, error: NSErrorPointer())//let's write the buffer result into our file

        }else{
             audioPlayerNode.removeTapOnBus(0)//if we dont remove it, will keep on tapping infinitely
            println("Did you like it? Please, vote up for my question")
        }

    }
```

**Hope this helps !**

**One issue to solve:**

Sometimes, your outputNode is shorter than the input: if you accelerate the time rate by 2, your audio will be 2 times shorter. This is the issue im facing for now since my condition for saving the file is (line 10)

```
if(newAudio.length) < (self.audioFile.length)//audiofile being the original(long) audio and newAudio being the new changed (shorter) audio.
```

**Any help here?**

Comment: Here: [Apple doc to export from AV](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_Export.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH9-SW2)

Comment: Thanks @eric D., i am going through the code. Looks like it will do the job. Nevertheless, there are many things i am discovering and many lines I have to understand. Is it ok if I raised questions?
For example, how could i load an Asset that is not a AudioFile with URL but an audioEngine or AudioNode?
Have you ever gone through this code?

Comment: Personnally, not really, I just thought you may have missed this doc, so I pasted the link. But that's not the problem: the thing is you can't ask too broad questions on SO. And comments are not the place for this anyway. I suggest you create a new question including your current code, showing what you try to achieve and where you struggle, or anything like that. Oh, and *one* topic per post. Welcome to SO, by the way. :)

Comment: Thank you,  i just signed up and this is my very first question. I
It doesnt seem as a broad question: 
AVAudioEngine to Audiofile?  I will post a new question more precise with the code ! 
Thank you again very much, your doc is very relevant, too bad i cant vote for your answer.

Comment: I meant *this* question is broad. :) And that's why I only posted a link to the docs in the comments. The question didn't fit for a proper answer. Anyway, it's all very well described [in the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's quite easy. You simply put a tap on a node and save the buffer into a file.

Unfortunately this means you have to *play* through the node. I was hoping that AVAudioEngine would let me process one sound file into another directly, but apparently that's impossible - you have to play and process in real time.

Comment: Thanks man, it helped me a lot.
One thing, I dont think you need to play if you install the tap on the audioNode. I havent tried it yet but I actually dont need it since i play the audio anyway before saving it. just like a sanity check.

Comment: Well, I'll try it again, but in my testing I couldn't get the file to save without actually playing through the buffers.

Comment: Can you provide the example to save new audio?

Answer (score 2):

Offline rendering Worked for me using GenericOutput AudioUnit. Please check this link, I have done mixing two,three audios offline and combine it to a single file. Not the same scenario but it may help you for getting some idea. [core audio offline rendering GenericOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297990/core-audio-offline-rendering-genericoutput/15361251#15361251)