# Export audio file after adding an effect

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I have an audio file that I want to process using some effects (like pitch effect) and then write the final result to a file.

Before I process the file and save it to disc I let the user play with the pitch effect and listen to the changes in real time.

this is how I do the real time stuff:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)

audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
audioFile = AVAudioFile(forReading: audioUrl!, error: nil)

audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)

changePitchEffect = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
changePitchEffect.pitch = 1.0 // default
audioEngine.attachNode(changePitchEffect)

audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: changePitchEffect, format: nil)
audioEngine.connect(changePitchEffect, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)

let frameCapacity = UInt32(audioFile.length)
let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: audioFile.processingFormat, frameCapacity: frameCapacity)
if audioFile.readIntoBuffer(buffer, error: nil) {

    audioEngine.startAndReturnError(nil)

    audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(buffer, atTime: nil, options: .Loops, completionHandler: nil)

    audioPlayerNode.play() // start playing in a loop
}
```

then using a `UISlider` I let the user change the value of the pitch while listening to the audio in a loop.

So when the user finishes playing with the pitch and taps the next button, I need to save the audio file with the chosen pitch value.

My question is, how do I create a new audio file with the pitch effect?

I don't want to record while the user is listening to the audio and play with the pitch effect, I only want to export the final result (without playing the file of course)

Answer (score 6):

Since using `AVAudioSession` is not an explicit requirement in the title of the question, there are 2 possible answers:

## Play through the node (with AVAudioSession)

Install a *tap* on the node. See [AV Foundation Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioNode_Class/index.html).

```
audioPlayerNode.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize:frameLength, format: audioInputNode.outputFormatForBus(0), block: {(buffer, time) in
    let channels = UnsafeArray(start: buffer.floatChannelData, length: Int(buffer.format.channelCount))
    let floats = UnsafeArray(start: channels[0], length: Int(buffer.frameLength))

    for var i = 0; i < Int(self.audioBuffer.frameLength); i+=Int(self.audioMixerNode.outputFormatForBus(0).channelCount)
    {
        // process
    }
})
```

The `AVAudioSession` tap mechanism requires play though. More about *recording while playing* on the [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127152/swift-is-it-possible-to-save-audio-from-avaudioengine-or-from-audioplayernode) by **@matt**.

---

## Use AudioUnit (without AVAudioSession)

Initialize an `AudioSession` with `AudioSessionInitialize` to play & record, set up a read & write stream, and pass a `AURenderCallbackStruct` pointing to your data processing code. This, however, precludes you from capitalizing upon `AVAudioUnitTimePitch`. You can find out more about this solution in this [How to do realtime recording with effect processing on iOS](http://teragonaudio.com/article/How-to-do-realtime-recording-with-effect-processing-on-iOS.html) article.

Comment: 10x for yr comment but regarding the first option, as I wrote, I dont want to record while playing. the second option is not clear to me, and I understand I wont be able to use the pitch effect