# Core Audio Offline rendering issue - output file has no audio

Tags: ios, core-audio, audio-recording

I have tried to implement the solution posted by @Abdusha in **[core audio offline rendering GenericOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15361251/2429443)**. Followed each step

The problem Im facing is that there is no sound in the output file. Though it is created with correct duration. Also the file size is around 100 Kb. Where as the input file is around 5.5mb in size. Has anyone else faced a similar issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the data read from the input file?

Comment: Yes the file is loaded and read properly. Still no luck

Comment: This is the result of ASBD file after calling AudioFileGetProperty

AU get input bus count | count: 2
Sample Rate:              44100
Format ID:           1633772320
Format Flags:                 0
Bytes per Packet:             0
Frames per Packet:         1024
Bytes per Frame:              0
Channels per Frame:           2
Bits per Channel:             0